# Can't empty trash

Tags: high-sierra, trash

I was working on a Node.js and Express project. I installed a module for TypeScript in VSCode for intellisense. I subsequently deleted the project, but it compiled those modules in .compile in same project and now I'm not able to delete this directory from Trash. Neither am I able put the item back to its original location.

How do I get rid of the item from the Trash?

Comment: Try by booting your Mac into [safe mode](https://support.apple.com/HT201262) and check if you can delete the file from Trash there.

Comment: I tried in safe mode also. It doesn't work

Comment: You might try running `rm -fr .Trash/*` from a terminal window (make sure you haven't cd'd out of your home directory first). Be careful: `rm -fr` is a powerful and dangerous command if used wrongly. For example, if you were to add a space before the `*`, you'd remove *all* of your files, including the `.Trash` directory! The first is disastrous, the latter is probably not desirable. You might get an error message pointing to the underlying cause of the problem. Report it here if so.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen add this to answer. It worked

Comment: Oh goodie! I added some detail in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try running `rm -fr .Trash/*` from a terminal window.

Make sure you haven't cd'd out of your home directory first. But foremost, be careful: `rm -fr` is a powerful and dangerous command if used wrongly. For example, if you were to add a space before the *, you'd remove *all* of your files, including the `.Trash` directory! The first is disastrous, the latter is probably not desirable.

It still might not succeed, due to files with flags set. In case you run into such problems, note that the `-O` (capital letter O) flag to `ls -l` will display any file flags. Run, e.g., `ls -AlOR .Trash` to see a listing of everything in `.Trash`, including their flags. Check the manual page for `chflags` to learn what flags exist, what they mean, and how to change them.

Answer (score -1):

I was running into a similar issue with node_modules* directories. I was able to get around it by renaming the files to something different - in my case I sed "fake-folder". Then I was able to delete them regularly from trash.